# Extract from Datastax Cassandra and load into HBase using Sqoop

Tags: cassandra, hbase, sqoop, datastax, sqoop2

I have 3 physical nodes running DSE 4.5. On the same 3 nodes I have HDP 2.2 running as well. Using Sqoop (either dse sqoop or sqoop provided by HortonWorks), how can I extract data from a Cassandra table and load into Hbase?

I have searched on the net and all examples describe RDBMS to HBase and vice versa or RDBMS to Cassandra and vice versa. Have not found any example for Cassandra to HBase i.e. NoSQL to NoSQL. The README.txt in /usr/share/dse/demos/sqoop also details import/export from mysql to cassandra.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The version of sqoop provided with DSE 4.5 does not support this. It only supports data transfer between RDBMS and NoSql not data transfer between NoSql and NoSql.